# Multiplying two values

Tags: angularjs

I am a beginner in `AngularJS` , but am totally confused , I want to multiply two values in the Text boxes to get the final answer, but this code is not multiplying them.
Please let me know where I am doing wrong .
Below is the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <title> PixsarApp Content Management System</title>
 <script src= "~/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
</head>
<body data-ng-app="Demo" >


     <h1>PixsarApp Content Management System</h1>



    Enter Numbers to Multiply: 
    <input type="text" data-ng-model="Num1" /> x <input type="text" data-ng-model="Num2" /> = <span>{{Num1*Num2}}</span>


</body>
</html>
```

Am using Visual Studio 2012.

[image]

My output

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to define angular module with name `Demo`, as you already specified `ng-app` with `Demo` module name. In current case it is failing because there is no module defined with the name `Demo`. Also refer `app.js` file on page after `angular.js` reference.

**app.js**

```
angular.module('Demo', [])
.controller('mainController', function($scope){
   $scope.Num1 = 0
   $scope.Num2 = 0
});
```

**Markup**

```
<head>
    <title> PixsarApp Content Management System</title>
    <script src= "~/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src= "~/Scripts/app.js"></script>
</head>
<body data-ng-app="Demo" ng-controller="mainController">
    <h1>PixsarApp Content Management System</h1>
    Enter Numbers to Multiply: 
    <input type="number" data-ng-model="Num1" /> 
    x 
    <input type="number" data-ng-model="Num2" /> 
    = 
    <span>{{Num1*Num2}}</span>
</body>
```

[**Demo Plunkr**](https://plnkr.co/edit/WSxrisn3TDMFYrb2Y9HY?p=preview)

---

Though the easy fix for your problem would be just to remove `data-ng-app="Demo"` from your html code. But as it would not be a good practice to run angular application without defining `module`. That's why I have the 1st part of answer. This para isn't what I recommend to do.

Comment: So create another script called app.js and i put insode the Scripts folder ? @Pankaj

Comment: @LutaayaHuzaifahIdris Although it would work by just removing `data-ng-app="Demo"` from your application, but best practice is create a module and attach components to it.. that would help you.. Thanks :)

Comment: It has still refused , check i've posted my output @Pankaj

Comment: @LutaayaHuzaifahIdris check console..do you have any errors in console/?

Comment: @LutaayaHuzaifahIdris have you looked at plunker which I provided to you?

Comment: Yeah i have tested it in the plunker and it's running , but why did you  **<script src="//code.angularjs.org/snapshot/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="app.js"></script>** , me am having this  **<script src= "~/Scripts/angular.js"></script>
    <script src= "~/Scripts/app.js"></script>** , isnt that the problem @Pankaj